# how to get a substring from a string in c#?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have strings stored in the format "domain\alias" and I need to store only the domain name in the second string. what is the shortest way of doing this? without any loop?

Comment: How are your strings stored? You should probably at least show what you have tried. Are they just in a list? Are you getting them from the DB?

Comment: String principalname = "middleeast\v-yanivf";

Comment: Sounds like Sujit has what you need then. Have fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public string GetUserNameFromServicePrinciple(string principleName)
        {
            string userName = principleName; //if input is just username and not a valid service principle name with domain

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(principleName))
            {

                var splittedParts = principleName.Split(@"\".ToCharArray());
                userName = splittedParts.Length > 1 ? splittedParts[1] : principleName;
            }

            return userName;
         }
```

Comment: this works but the only issue is that my string is principalname(a variable) so prefixing it with the symbol @ doesn't work. thanks!

Comment: how do i adjust @ here:
 fullName1= "middleeast\v-yanivf";
          
            var parts = fullName1.Split('\\');
            var domain = parts[0]; //check the length of array to ensure it has elements.

Comment: Hi Siddharth, var domainFOrmattedString = @"domainTest......" is just an example. In your application you must have user's principle name coming in the variable so you would not have to put @ before the variable.

Comment: Hi sunil, I tried the below code but it doesn't help:
var string1 = "fareast\v-sidmis";
            var parts = string1.Split('\\');
            var domain = parts[0];
            Console.WriteLine(domain);

Comment: Can you please edit your post and put the code in there? It will be good to see proper formatted code

Comment: My code is something like this:
var domainFormattedString ;
var parts = domainFormattedString.Split('\\');
var domainString = parts[0]; 

this is the code provided by you, but the only change here is that my string domainformattedstring comes from the user side as a input so how do i use your logic here....if i use @ before the string....i do not get the requuired result.

Comment: Why does user enter domain\username? 

Are you getting that input value in one of the variable? Is value added in a textbox or selected from a list?

Comment: yes I am getting the input value in a variable and then i want to split the content of that variable in two different strings....one will contain the doamin name and the other contains the alias...thats it!

Comment: Hi Siddharth, I have updated my answer with a method which takes a user principle name or just username and return the username.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks sujit! I really appreciate your help. let me just check it out and respond back.

Comment: Hi I tried this:
 fullName1 = "fareast\v-sidmis";
            string userName = fullName1; //if input is just username and not a valid service principle name with domain

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullName1))
            {

                var splittedParts = fullName1.Split(@"\".ToCharArray());
                userName = splittedParts.Length > 1 ? splittedParts[1] : fullName1;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(userName);
            Console.ReadKey();
but the o/p is not as expected.It is displaying ascii value of '\'. :(

Comment: In your testing code you need to put extra '\' character. Single '\' is treated as escape character hence \v will be ignored in the string.

This code will work if you test it against input from UI or reading from variables (such as WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name). Following tests are passing:

 System.Console.WriteLine(GetUserNameFromServicePrinciple("fareast\\v-sidmis"));
            System.Console.WriteLine(GetUserNameFromServicePrinciple(Environment.UserName));
            System.Console.WriteLine(GetUserNameFromServicePrinciple(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name));

Comment: so what is the final code then...because my variable will always have the values in the form domain\alias.

Comment: Same code is final code, when you are trying the code you need to put two \\ instead of one in the hardcoded value. C# considers one \ as escaping character.

for input data it should be fine. if you input domain\username in the input control (textbox etc) it will work fine

Comment: Oh i see let me verify this and get back to you.

Comment: just one question...will it also work correctly if I read the value from a database and store it in a string?

Comment: hey dotnetman, do you mind accepting my answer if it helps please.

Comment: did that....since i have only 13 points i won't be able to plus 1 your answer....thanks a ton man....could you also give me plus 1 for question?